# Masonry Rails stopped working in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-masonry

I have come across an issue with my Rails 4 app where I have a photo gallery utilizing the masonry-rails gem. It is essentially the same as John Elders Pinterest clone, but with a "photos" class instead of "pins" class. It's all tied in through Pundit for CRUD operations. It was working perfectly for a few months until recently it stopped. I have uninstalled and reinstalled, but continue to get the same error message in the console:

```
Started GET "/photos" for 48.153.148.26 at 2017-02-14 17:01:17 +0000
Cannot render console from 48.153.148.26! Allowed networks: 128.0.0.1, ::1, 128.0.0.0/128.255.255.255
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by PhotosController#index as HTML
DEPRECATION WARNING: [paperclip] [deprecation] AWS SDK v1 has been deprecated in paperclip 5. Please consider upgrading to AWS 2 before upgrading paperclip. (called from warn at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/paperclip-4.3.7/lib/paperclip/deprecations.rb:38)
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.195071 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.195490 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.203122 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.203470 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.208150 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.208470 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.216605 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.216975 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.221868 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.223774 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.228292 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.230086 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.235929 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.236274 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.241211 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.241558 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.250426 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.251149 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.256320 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
W, [2017-02-14T17:01:18.258134 #20170]  WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#count defined in Enumerable. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.
  Photo Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "photos".* FROM "photos"  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
  Rendered photos/index.html.erb within layouts/application (20.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered application/_favicon.html.erb (19.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_date.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_date.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (9.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (2.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2382ms (Views: 1931.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

I have searched and searched but cannot find any similar code errors posted anywhere. I think it might be caused by another gem because it was working fine until I ran a bundle update. Also, I had a WYSIWIG gem for styling posts that stopped working after the bundle update. I have since replaced it with Bootsy WYSWIG and that gem works perfect, but Masonry-Rails still does not.

Here is my code:

Gem File

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.1'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
gem 'active_link_to', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'ionicons-rails', '~> 2.0'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.6'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'masonry-rails', '~> 0.2.4'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'
gem 'mail_form', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'
gem 'bootsy', '~> 2.3', '>= 2.3.1'
gem 'rails_real_favicon', '~> 0.0.3'
gem 'instagram', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.6'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1'
gem 'faker', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.6'
gem 'pundit', '~> 1.1'
gem 'papercrop', '~> 0.3.0'
gem 'dotenv-rails', :require => 'dotenv/rails-now'
gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
gem 'jquery-smooth-scroll-rails'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.11'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.2'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.10', '>= 2.10.1'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.7'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.3'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'pundit-matchers', '~> 1.1.0'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
end
```

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.jcrop
//= require papercrop
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery-smooth-scroll
//= require bootsy
//= require customjs
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require_tree .
```

Application.css

```
 *
 *= require bootsy
 *= require 'masonry/transitions'
 *= require jquery.jcrop
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Custom JS file

```
/*-------------------------------------------*/
           /* MASONRY RAILS */
/*-------------------------------------------*/
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(function() {
   return $('#photos').imagesLoaded(function() {
     return $('#photos').masonry({
       itemSelector: ".box",
       isFitWidth: true
     });
   });
 });
});
```

Photos page index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Gallery") %>
<div class="container sports">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div id="photos masonry-container" class="transitions-enabled">
        <% @photos.each do |photo| %>

            <div class="box">
              <div class="panel">
                <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image.url(:medium)), photo  %><br>
                <% if current_user&.admin? || current_user&.editor? %>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                   <%= photo.description %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-footer center">
                    <p>Posted by: <%= photo.user&.username %><br>
                    <% if policy(photo).update? %>
                      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_photo_path(photo) %> |
                    <% end %>
                    <% if policy(photo).destroy? %>
                      <%= link_to 'Delete', photo, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>

        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        <%= will_paginate @photos, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Everything else with the gallery works perfectly including Paperclip and Pundit. Seems to be a javascript bug somewhere or a conflicting updated gem, but I have no clue about Hashies. Any help is greatly appreciated!

--UPDATE--
To clear up what my exact problem is: when I view the photos index page, my photos are stacked vertically instead of horizontally as the Masonry gem with the transitions script should do. It used to be perfect, but after the bundle update, the photos do not line up horizontally anymore.

Comment: What exactly is the error here/the problem? What you see in the console is just a warning/deprecation message. Most likely it shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: Instead of the images lining up next to each other and dynamically shifting as the screen shrinks and grows as the masonry gem should do, they are just stacked vertically and do not move at all.